# Sinatra NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I'm trying to use a Haml file in my Ruby app, but I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /issues

undefined method `map' for "localhost:27017":String 

index.haml in block in singleton class
9.  -@issues.each do |issue|

app.rb in block in <class:App>
14.     haml :"issues/index"
```

Here is my index.haml file:

```
%h1 All Issues

%table.table.table-hover
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Title
      %th Description
      %th Created at
  -@issues.each do |issue|
    %tr
      %td
        %a(href="/issues/#{issue.id}/edit")=issue.name
      %td=issue.description 
      %td=issue.id.generation_time.ago_in_words 
  -unless @issues.any?
    %tfoot
      %tr
        %th
          There are no issues.
          %a.btn.btn-primary(href="/issues/new") Create one
```

And here is the app.rb file:

```
require_relative "models/issue"

class App < Sinatra::Base
  enable :sessions
  register Sinatra::Flash

  get "/" do
    "redirect/issues" 
  end   

  get "/issues" do 
    @issues = Issue.all 

    haml :"issues/index"
  end   
end
```

The problem seems to be with my -@issues.each do |issue| loop, but I'm note sure if the problem is with Ruby Syntax or Haml, or something else. I've also created an issue.rb file in my /models directory that looks like this:

```
class Issue 
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated

  field :name, type: String
  field :description, type: String
end
```

Edit: I think my problem is that Issue is not initialized. I'm getting an error that says:

```
uninitialized constant Issue::Mongoid (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is that there's no space left between the hypen and the Ruby code following it. I'm not sure if that actually makes a difference to the way Haml is parsed, but [all the examples in the Haml reference leave a space](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#running_ruby_), e.g.

```
-@issues.each do |issue|
```

should be

```
- @issues.each do |issue|
```

Next thing to check in the value of `Issues.all`, either by some debugging with something like [pry](http://pryrepl.org/) or just use `warn` to output it to the console, e.g.

```
@issues = Issue.all
warn @issues
```

or

```
binding.pry
@issues = Issue.all
```

The `-unless @issues.any?` line in the index.haml may benefit from being changed too. [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) is usually called with a block, `- if @issues.empty?` would (IMO) be easier to grok than an `unless` with a less well used version of a method.

Comment: Adding a space after the hyphen doesn't seem to do anything. I used warn @issues and binding.pry and I got this error for the issue.rb file: `uninitialized constant Issue::Mongoid (NameError)`

Comment: @KristineRooks is `require 'mongoid'` in the model file?

Comment: How did you configure mongoid in sinatra blog? Did you use a `mongoid.yml` file or a `Mongoid.configure` block?
Since the error showed calling map onto "localhost:27017", which is mongodb host, it can be some configuration error in connecting to mongodb. What I am guessing is hosts: option given "localhost:27017" , instead of ["localhost:27017"]? I may be wrong though.

Comment: @dreamingblackcat I think you have to "@" Kristine [or a notification isn't sent to them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39693/receive-notifications-for-comments-on-any-answers-to-your-question?rq=1).

Comment: @KristineRooks please read my coment regarding mongoid configuration.